# Determining an analytic function uniquely from its level lines

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functions, analytic-functions

Let $f: \mathbb{R}^d \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be an analytic function, with infinite radius of convergence at any point $x \in \mathbb{R}^d$, where $d>1$ (and, in particular, $d=2$). It is clear that, if we are given the restriction of $f$ to any open set, this is enough to determine $f$ on the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$, since we can just evaluate the Taylor series of $f$ at some $x_0$ in this open set.

Suppose we are now given the level lines of $f$ instead; $f^{-1}(\{0\}) := \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^d : f(x) = 0 \}$. Is this enough to determine $f$ uniquely (up to multiplicative constant)? What if we are only given one connected component of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$? Or even just the (nontrivial) intersection of one connected component of $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ with an open set? Are these enough to determine $f$ uniquely, modulo constant?

I have been told that all of these are enough to uniquely determine $f$, but have been unable to find a convincing reference or intution for why this might be the case, unlike when we view $f$ on an open set.

Comment: The level set $f^{-1}(\{0\})$ alone is far from enough to specify $f$ up to multiplicative constant. For instance, for $d = 1$ think about $f_1(x) = x^2 - 1$ and $f_2(x) = x^4 - 1$. I suppose you meant some family of level sets $\{f^{-1}(\{\lambda\}) \, | \, \lambda \in \Lambda\}$ for some $\Lambda \subset \mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Oh yes good point, I'm mainly interested in the case $d = 2$ so is the answer potentially different when $d > 1$? I have edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: What I am trying to point out is not about the number of dimensions. For $d=2$ notice that $f_1(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 - 1$ and $f_2(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)^2 - 1$ have the same zero set $f_1^{-1}(\{0\}) = f_2^{-1}(\{0\}) = \textrm{the unit circle}$. Notice also that the zero set might be empty, like for the functions $f_3(x,y) = x^2 + y^2 + 1$ and $f_4(x,y) = (x^2 + y^2)^2 + 1$. To have a chance of reconstructing a non-zero function $f$, you need many more level sets $f^{-1}(\{\lambda\})$ for various $\lambda$'s other than $0$.